# cryptonite: Why is `digestFromByteString` Nothing?

Tags: haskell, cryptography

I'm trying to verify a signature on a web request. I need to compute an HMAC with the SHA256 hash function using my secret as the key and a signed payload as the message, then compare that with the signature.

The signature looks like this:
`0d586561d8f896e52d5c4a2147609fdf74eb72e7bcb3a3756b89fcbef88a94b3`

It seems like `cryptonite` is the right library for this, so I'm using hmac from Crypto.MAC.HMAC. Here's what I have so far:

```hs
case digestFromByteString signature of
  Nothing -> return False
  Just signatureDigest ->
    return $ signatureDigest `constEq` hmacGetDigest (hmac secret signedPayload :: HMAC SHA256)
```

Visually the digest and the signature look the same. If I convert both sides to strings, the strings are equal.

```
show hmacHash == T.unpack (T.decodeUtf8 signature) -- This is True!
```

But I can't even get so far as `constEq` because when I use `digestFromByteString` to convert the signature string into a digest, it fails. Why?

(Also if I'm barking up the wrong tree on anything else, please let me know.)

Answer (score 4):

I finally found out the answer from a Google search that lead to an old Gitter discussion.

Even though `digestFromByteString` will take a hex-encoded ByteString, it doesn't know what to do with it. I had to use `memory`'s `convertFromBase` to convert from base16.

I added this before my conversion to the digest, and now everything works!

```hs
case convertFromBase Base16 hexSignature of
  Left err -> return False
  Right signature -> ...
```

(Leaving this unanswered in case anyone who actually knows about cryptonite can explain the "why" better...)

Comment: 6 years later and this solved the same issue I was having. I think the documentation probably needs to make this clearer.